# How do I get node.js running in a docker container to resolve DNS through Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am building an API in node.js and want it to communicate to some of my other dockers on my server.
However, the node.js DNS Resolution is not working as it should be;  It fails to find a the local ip of a container even when specifying the docker DNS Host (127.0.0.11).

See my steps in the below capture --  set up a resolver, set it to resolve through Docker's Host, then attempt to resolve with an error. Dig Finds it just fine through the same Host

```
root@6f99a9ade736:/app# node
Welcome to Node.js v13.6.0.                                                 
Type ".help" for more information.
> const { Resolver } = require('dns');
undefined
> const resolver = new Resolver();
undefined
> resolver.setServers(['127.0.0.11'])
undefined
> reolver.resolve4('Postgres11',console.log)
Uncaught ReferenceError: reolver is not defined
> resolver.resolve4('Postgres11',console.log)
QueryReqWrap {
bindingName: 'queryA',
callback: [Function: bound consoleCall],
hostname: 'Postgres11',
oncomplete: [Function: onresolve],
ttl: false
}
> Error: queryA ENOTFOUND Postgres11
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:206:19) {
errno: undefined,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'queryA',
hostname: 'Postgres11'
}
^D

root@6f99a9ade736:/app# dig Postgres11
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> Postgres11
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65008
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;Postgres11.                    IN      A
;; ANSWER SECTION:
Postgres11.             600     IN      A       172.18.0.3
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.11#53(127.0.0.11)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 27 12:32:27 MST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd:
root@6f99a9ade736:/app#
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you looked into [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)? compose sets up the networking for you, you don't need to mess around with DNS.

Comment: This is a good question. Sadly it may not get the attention it deserves due to a lack of context. The phrase "communicate to some of my other dockers" could possibly be expanded to provide more helpful context. This is could be important for example The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts are you running on Linux ? This is where context helps.

Comment: @NigelSavage I am running this on an unraid server.I have not looked into using docker-compose, rather I am directly running this through the unraid docker manager after building the container.

Comment: Do you need to `dns.setResolvers()`?  (The Node docs suggest that, without it, `Resolver` "uses the default server settings".)  Does `dns.lookup()` work instead (with slightly different semantics)?

Comment: Is this resolved @EricBell. If so please let us know what was the solution ?